# Complement notation in sets, how do you specify a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am currently reading:

> How to think like a mathematician
>   By Kevin Houston

Early in the book it defines difference ( in sets) in terms of $X$ and $Y$ and then states that is if $Y$ is a subset of $X$ we can call $X\setminus Y$ the complement of $Y$ in $X$ and denote this by $Y^{c}$

Later on in the book it uses this complement notation more and I was just curious to know how you could refer to which set the complement was in if say $Y$ was a subset of $A$ and $B$ how would write these individually?

Comment: $A\setminus Y$ and $B\setminus Y$.

Comment: So as soon as multiple sets are involved the notation of $Y^{c}$ is not valid?

Comment: The notation $Y^{\complement}$ can be ambiguous---the complement relative to *what*?  It is a shorthand that should really only be used when there is no risk of confusion.

Comment: No because as you noticed, it is unclear and would lead to confusion.

Comment: @SonnyDaSilva-Peters I suppose it would be valid as long as the reader can understand which subset the complement refers to--like if you say "Let $Y^{C}$ denote the set $A \setminus Y$" or something

Comment: "compliment" implies there is a "universal" set $X$ that contains everything worth considering.  So $Y^c = X \setminus Y$.  If you want to indicate simply the elements of $A$ and $B$ that aren't in $Y$ you use $A\setminus Y$ and $B\setminus Y$.  You might like to know $A\setminus Y = A \cap Y^c$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I thought you might be able to use subscript such as $Y^{c}_A$ but alas it seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $Y$ is a subset of $A$ the complement is $A\backslash Y$. You use the complement notation $Y^c$ only when you want the complement in the universe of discourse at the moment: the set of everything you are talking about at the moment. So in the integers, $\text{odds}^c = \text{evens}$ but in the real numbers you'd have to write
$\text{integers}\backslash \text{odds}$ since $\text{odds}^c$ would be all the real numbers that weren't odd integers.